# Django - Get the absolute URL when using .values()

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a user model with many fields

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/avatar', default='users/avatar/avatar.png')
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    member_since = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

In a particular view, I am interested in retrieving just the username and the avatar of the user, so I can return a JSON response, so I do the following:

```
users = User.objects.values('username', 'avatar')
```

That will return me a list of dictionaries with the following data:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'username': 'A', 'avatar': 'users/avatar/avatar.png'}, 
    {'username': 'B', 'avatar': 'users/avatar/avatar.png'}, 
    {'username': 'C', 'avatar': 'users/avatar/avatar.png'}
]>
```

Notice that the URL for the avatar is a relative one. How could I get the absolute URL without having to retrieve all the fields of the user?

I'd like to get the following:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'username': 'A', 'avatar': 'http://example.com/media/users/avatar/avatar.png'}, 
    {'username': 'B', 'avatar': 'http://example.com/media/users/avatar/avatar.png'}, 
    {'username': 'C', 'avatar': 'http://example.com/media/users/avatar/avatar.png'}
]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was facing the same issue a week ago in Django in which I am getting image name from an object but I want to access image URL.

So what I was doing is, I was retrieving an item as follows:

```py
items = Item.objects.all()

for item in items:
    print({'item_name':item.name, 'item_url': item.image})
```

So above code gave me item name and item image name instead of the item url so I go through one step deeper and check item.image attribute and I got URL from item.image.url

```py
for item in items:
    print({'item_name':item.name, 'item_url': item.image.url})
```

so in your case, you can do something like:

```py
users = User.objects.values('username', 'avatar')
for user in users:
    print({'username': user.username, 'avatar': avatar.image.url})
```

if you are still not getting your image URL in avatar.image.url then just try avatar.image. And check all attributes in python debugger. If you still have any doubts regarding this then you can ask in comment.

Comment: If add to build an URL as well and I've been inspired by this code https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/f70cb3d622f992f15fe9b57098e0b328445b664e/allauth/utils.py#L259 Maybe it can help you if you can't get absolute URL.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see many good answers here so I'll throw my not-great answer in the ring in hopes it sparks some ideas.

If you use Django's `Sites` app:

```
from django.comf import settings
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

users = User.objects.all().annotate(
    scheme=Value('http://'),
    domain=Subquery(Site.objects.filter(name='example.com').values('domain')),
    media_url=Value(settings.MEDIA_URL),
).annotate(absolute_url=Concat('scheme', 'domain', 'media_url', 'avatar'))
```

To see if the annotation worked for you, do:

```
users.values('absolute_url')
```

Unless I am mistaken, you should see something like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'absolute_url': 'http://example.com/media/users/avatar/avatar.png'},
    {'absolute_url': 'http://example.com/media/users/avatar/avatar.png'},
    {'absolute_url': 'http://example.com/media/users/avatar/avatar.png'},
    ...
]>
```

You could concatenate different values together like username:

```
User.objects.all().annotate(
    scheme=Value('http://'),
    domain=Subquery(Site.objects.filter(name='example.com').values('domain')),
    media_url=Value(settings.MEDIA_URL),
    avatar=Value('users/avatar/avatar.png'),
).annotate(absolute_url=Concat(
    'scheme', 'domain', 'media_url', 'username', Value('/'), 'avatar')
).values('absolute_url')
```

To get:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'absolute_url': 'http://example.com/media/A/users/avatar/avatar.png'},
    {'absolute_url': 'http://example.com/media/B/users/avatar/avatar.png'},
    {'absolute_url': 'http://example.com/media/C/users/avatar/avatar.png'},
    ...
]>
```